# Minimising area under the ROC curve to optimise the parameters of a polynomial predictor with optim

Tags: r, roc, polynomials, nonlinear-optimization, minimization

My predictor (x) has U-shaped distribution in relation to the binary outcome (y), with positive outcomes at both low and high values of x, leading to a biconcave `roc` curve with a poor area under the curve (`auc`).

To maximise its ability to discriminate the outcome, I am trying to optimise the parameters of a second grade polynomial of x, by using `optim` and `1 - auc` as the cost function to minimise.

```
x = c(13,7,7,7,1,100,3,4,4,2,2,7,14,8,3,14,5,12,8,
      13,9,4,9,4,8,3,13,9,4,4,5,9,10,10,7,6,12,7,2,
      6,6,4,3,2,3,10,5,2,5,8,3,5,4,2,7,5,7,6,79,9)

y = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)

theta = c(0, 0, 0)

min_auc <- function(theta, x, y) {
  (1 - roc(y, (theta[1] + theta[2]*x + theta[3]*x^2))$auc)
}

optim(theta, min_auc, x = x, y = y)
```

The results are as follow:

```
$par
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.0

$value
[1] 0.4380054

$counts
function gradient 
       8       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

However, from a manual definition of the parameters, I know that `min_auc` can be further minimised.

```
theta = c(0, -40, 1)
(1 - roc(y, (theta[1] + theta[2]*x + theta[3]*(x^2)))$auc)

[1] 0.2762803
```

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong, please? Is it possibly due to a non-convex cost function?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is it's a collinearity problem.  Scaling the inputs helps:

```
min_auc <- function(theta, x, y) {
  (1 - roc(y, (theta[1] + theta[2]*scale(x) + theta[3]*scale(x)^2))$auc)
}

optim(theta, min_auc, x = x, y = y)
# $par
# [1] -0.02469136 -0.03117284  0.11049383
# 
# $value
# [1] 0.2762803
# 
# $counts
# function gradient 
# 30       NA 
# 
# $convergence
# [1] 0
# 
# $message
# NULL
#
```

Another potential problem is that the surface over which you're optimizing has some flat spots.  Let's say, for example, that we fix the intercept in this equation to -2.  This is about what you get if you do `qlogis(mean(y))`.  Then, you're only optimizing over 2 parameters so the surface is easier to see. Here's what it looks like with the two remaining theta terms on the two horizontal axes and the 1-AUC value on the y-axis.

```
min_auc <- function(theta, x, y) {
  (1 - roc(y, (-2 + theta[1]*scale(x) + theta[2]*scale(x)^2))$auc)
}
s <- seq(-.25, .25, length=50)
o <- outer(s, s, Vectorize(function(z,w)min_auc(c(z,w),x,y)))

library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = ~s, y = ~s, z = ~o) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

As you may have noticed above, there is no unique solution to the problem.  There are lots of solutions that seem to get to the minimum value.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand the rationale behind the need for scaling. Regarding the presence of flat minimum areas, is that due to the limited sample size of this cohort or are there other factors behind it?